# Why do I get DAC error even though it is disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, dac

I get the following error sometimes:

> Could not connect because the maximum number of '1' dedicated
> administrator connections already exists. Before a new connection can
> be made, the existing dedicated administrator connection must be
> dropped, either by logging off or ending the process

DAC is not enabled on the SQL server. What can cause this error?

Comment: Are you sure DAC is not enabled? DAC itself is enabled by default; it's just "remote" DAC that needs to be enabled with the RemoteDACEnabled or "remote admin connections" options.

Comment: Ok the error I'm seeing is DAC or remote DAC?

Comment: From what I can see, the error doesn't specify. It could be a local DAC connection or a remote one. But if remote DAC is not enabled on your server, that only leaves a local DAC connection as the cause of the message.

Comment: So does this mean a sysadmin user made a connection to SQL server from the same server? I'm confused as there is no other sysadmin account (only I'm the sysadmin).

Comment: Maybe. This query should tell you. `select 
CASE
WHEN es.session_id= @@SPID THEN 'you are :)'
ELSE es.host_name
END AS Who_is_running_DAC,
es.original_login_name,
es.session_id,
es.login_time,
es.status
from sys.endpoints as ep
join sys.dm_exec_sessions es on
ep.endpoint_id=es.endpoint_id
where ep.name='Dedicated Admin Connection'`

Comment: But DAC happens only when I connect  using admin: and 1434 port isn't it?

Comment: Yes, either prefixing the instance name with "admin:" or by using the -A switch with SQLCMD.

Comment: @variable Did you get this error when connecting from SSMS? If so be sure it is SSMS that use Intellisense or open ObjectExplorer that use the same connection string that you provided but it did it **prior** that it offers you any "query" window

Comment: I saw these errors in error log. I am the only sysadmin and during the error occurence I wasn't working. So I'm puzzled as to what has caused this